# SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer cannot open some files via File Path

Tags: superpowered

Calling `SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer::open("/data/user/0/com.superpowered.crossexample/files/CROSS/tune.wav")` 
for an audio file (.wav) with duration 2.53 Minutes and file size 45.8 MB results in SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerEvent_LoadError.

It works fine if the file is put in assets and loaded with AssetFileDescriptor

But if loaded via file path on of it fails. (files links attached)

```
playerB->open("/data/user/0/com.superpowered.crossexample/files/CROSS/tune.wav");
```

but loaded with file path exist in-app and returns true for file object with file exist.

have two files loaded via string path, attached both the files. one of it loads perfectly and another doesn't.

this file opens via file path and AssetFileDescriptor both
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rpPIB3Q2EmSzcTnD_9pPecrF7zGt3Xkr

this file opens via only AssetFileDescriptor and not file path open->("/data/user/0/com.superpowered.crossexample/files/CROSS/tune.wav");
https://drive.google.com/open?id=18HKSmYHx3CDNfKmd4hWFuKj_AF1AIKyW

Please help.

Comment: I put your file like     player->open("/storage/emulated/0/rec.wav"); but it does not work... please help how we can open file from internal storage memory

Comment: @nidhi i was able to open with above code. my mistake was to not set crossfader value.

Hope you also got your issue resolved. Ping me here if not.

Comment: actually, I am not able to understand the cpp code.Can you explain how I can take mp3 file fron internal storage? At which place I have to change in crossExample of superpowered?

Comment: Sure, ping me on skype. @ skype-id : cattechsol.com i can help you out as i have spend good amount on time understanding this and implementing this.
I'll help you out

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to open with the above code. my mistake was to not set crossfader value.

Thank you